# Having trouble running ng lint on a directory

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I'm attempting to use the linter that comes with Angular 8, but I've neglected TSLint errors for a while. I'm hoping to slowly clean up the errors, and I'm searching for a way to run the linter on entire directories, some of which may have multiple subdirectories.

I've looked at the [Angular documentation for ng lint](https://angular.io/cli/lint), but I'm not finding anything helpful (or I may be overlooking something). What I thought I was looking for was the `--files` flag, but I must be doing something wrong, because when I run `ng lint --files`, I can only get it to work with a single file, and not an entire directory.

For example, using `ng lint --files src/app/+register/registration.component.ts` works perfectly.

Does anybody have any thoughts on this? I'd love some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just run `ng lint` on the project?

Comment: @R.Richards Right, I can do that, but I want to run it on specific directories and not the entire project...

Comment: You would think you could use a glob with the `--file` option, but I can't tell if it really works like that. `ng lint --files=src/app/folder/**/*.ts`

Comment: @R.Richards Yep, that works perfectly. I didn't know I was able to use a glob. If you want to make that the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a glob, or wildcard, to get the functionality you need. Example below.

```
ng lint --files=src/app/folder/**/*.ts
```

Comment: Can someone please break down the meaning of the wildcard syntax?  `/**/` and `*.ts`.

Comment: This files option seems to have been deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

For those like me who visit this question some years later with a newer Angular version:

```
ng lint --lint-file-patterns=src/app/your/path/**/*.ts
```

tested on Angular 14

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found this solution:

```
ng lint [ Project name ] --files '[ Directory path ]/*.ts'
```

Change between the brackets with your own options.

You can use [ ** ] for the unknown directory.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using ESLint instead of TSLint the below option is not working:

```
ng lint --files=src/app/folder/**/*.ts
```

Instead, you can use:

```
ng lint --lint-file-patterns=src/app/folder/**/*.ts
```