# ESLint doesn't check Cypress files

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, eslint

My project is written in Angular 13 and Typescript and with `eslint`. Later on I've added Cypress. And when I run command `ng lint` it doesn't check files inside `/cypress` folder. But when I use Visual Studio Code it correctly finds errors.

```
.eslintrc.json

{
    "root": true,
    "ignorePatterns": [
        "projects/**/*",
        "cypress/fixtures/**/*",
        "cypress/integration-original/**/*.js",
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.mock.ts"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": [
                "*.ts"
            ],
            "parserOptions": {
                "project": [
                    "tsconfig.json",
                    "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                ],
                "createDefaultProgram": true
            },
            "extends": [
                "eslint:recommended",
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
            ],
            "plugins": [
                "deprecation"
            ],
            "rules": { ...  }
        },
        {
            "files": [
                "*.html"
            ],
            "extends": [
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
            ],
            "rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

In Angular project, folder structure is:

```
-cypress
-node_modules
-src
.eslintrc.json
tsconfig.json
...
```

Comment: You should also add how you execute Eslint. Very likely there you can find the issue.

Comment: I issue `npm run lint` which is `ng lint` - mentioned in description.

Comment: And what does "ng" do? Is it some CLI from Angular?

Comment: Yes, it is CLI: https://angular.io/cli/lint

Comment: Then this can help you very likely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274165/15090924

Comment: I know I can specify folder to lint as a parameter. But I want to issue single command to scan all folders (`src`, `cypress`) without specyfying them literally as parameters.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?.

Im trying to run `npm run lint` in angular project, it doesnt detect the cypress files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added in `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html",
              "cypress"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```